# Find the probability generating function of $2X$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X$ follows a poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ (mean). Then find the probability generating function of $2X$.

I'm getting stuck with forming the expression, as I'm getting confused with what values $2X$ will take.
Please help.

Comment: Well, it will only take even values (or $0$), so it's not Poisson.

Comment: But $X$ is right.

Comment: Yes, X is poisson as defined in your post. I've added a hint to help you along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y=2X$. Then,
\begin{align*}
G(t)&=E[t^{Y}]=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}t^{y}P(Y=y)
=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}t^{y}P(2X=y)
=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}t^{y}P(X=y/2)\\
&=P(X=0)+t^{1}P(X=1/2)+t^{2}P(X=1)+t^{3}P(X=3/2)+t^{4}P(X=2)+\ldots \\
&=P(X=0)+0+t^{2}P(X=1)+0+t^{4}P(X=2)+\ldots \\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} t^{2x}P(X=x)+\ldots \\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}t^{2x}\frac{\lambda^xe^{-\lambda}}{x!}
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks but I already solved it.

Comment: To make it simpler, you could directly write the function as $E[t^{2X}]=E[(t^{2})^{X}]. After that it is trivial.

Comment: @user210292 you should accept one answer so that the question doesn't remain "unanswered"

Comment: @VladimirVargas okay

Comment: Originally what you're saying is what I had but I decided to add extra steps...